# Discord.js login with multiple accounts

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a script that react a specified message when I type "test" to discord chat.
The problem is that it will login to only one account and I need login to 2 or more accounts.
What can be the problem?

My full code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();


    // load client
    client.on("ready", () => {
        console.log((`Logged in to Discord as: ${(client.user.tag)}`));
        console.log('--------------------------------------' + '-'.repeat(client.user.tag))
    });



client.on('message', (msg) => {

  if(msg.content === 'test') {
      const chan = msg.guild.channels.get('609754363896008725');
      if(chan == null) {
          return;
      }

      msg.channel.fetchMessage('715520862239294484').then(data => {
          data.react('');
      })
      console.log('done :-D');
  }

})


const tokens = ["token1", "token2"];

for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    client.login(tokens[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One Discord client can only log into one account.

You need multiple clients. If you *really* need to do it this way you can keep an array of clients and loop over them.